# When creating a user by Membership.CreateUser, is there a .NET wrapper that can set the user's address, city, state, zip, etc.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I've been Googling this for about 30 minutes now to no avail.  It seems like it would be straight forward.  But basically, I'm creating a new user via code by `Memebership.CreateUser(...)`.  I need to set the user's address, city, state, etc.  I would imagine this would be the user's profile.  Is there not a .NET wrapper (like `Membership`) that I can use to do this?  How in the world do I set this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure a ProfileProvider in your web.config.
Later in your code, you could create a Profile for that user, and set the properties needed (Name, Address, etc.).
Here is a tutorial by Scott Mitchell, on [ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx)

There are different implementations of Profile Providers, also you can do one yourself.
I suggest you to try Sql Stored Procedure Profile Provider or Table Profile Provider.

The framework provides *SqlProfileProvider*. You can read it in the link provided.

It says "After defining your Profile properties, the ASP.NET engine automatically creates a **ProfileCommon** class that has properties that map to the properties defined in Web.config (which allows for IntelliSense and compile-time type checking). This class is dynamically recreated whenever the properties defined in Web.config are modified ..."

"The custom ProfileCommon class is accessible in the code portion of an ASP.NET page through the HttpContext object's **Profile** property. For example, to read the currently logged on user's HomepageUrl property from an ASP.NET page, simply use Profile.HomepageUrl..."

But using *SqlProfileProvider* is not a good implementation, as it saves all custom properties, such as address, phone, etc, in two columns in a single row. That's why I suggested investigate Stored Procedure or Table Profile Provider.

Comment: Is there really not a .NET wrapper for the user's profile that I can use?

Comment: Maybe not for this project, but if you have the time I suggest to look into [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) which is, as they say, "a fresh look" on membership system in modern apps. In this scenario, among many other things, you could have the address, city, etc properties in same User class or model, or if you prefer in another one, calling it what you like (Profile, UserDetails, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an another table and use foreign key as UserId i.e. UniqueIdentifier and same used in aspnet_Users table.

Using the UserId you can manage all membership tables with this new created table.bcoz asp_net_membership table already linked with aspnet_user table.

When the status of membership create user will be success, then create a row in newly created table..

Comment: There has to be a .NET wrapper for this, just like `Membership`, is there not one?